# Encoding error on windows when code runs fine on linux

Tags: python, linux, windows, encoding

I use the following code to break a bunch of .xls files into .csv files.

```
import sys
import os
import xlrd

def explode(inputFile):
    try:
        os.mkdir(inputFile+".folder")
    except OSError:
        chill = None
    with xlrd.open_workbook(inputFile) as wb:
        for k in range(0,wb.nsheets):
            sh = wb.sheet_by_index(k) # or wb.sheet_by_name('name_of_the_sheet_here')
            with open(inputFile+".folder"+"/sheet"+str(k)+".csv", 'w') as f:
                ret = ""
                for r in range(sh.nrows):
                    for col in sh.row_values(r):
                        try:
                            ret+=str(col)+","
                        except UnicodeEncodeError:
                            ret+=","
                    ret = ret[:-1]
                    ret+="\n"
                ret = ret[:-1]
                f.write(ret)


dataDir = sys.argv[1]

os.chdir(dataDir)

Files = [name for name in os.listdir(".") if not os.path.isdir(name)]

for k in Files:
    explode(k)


os.chdir("..")
```

This works well enough on my machine (Ubuntu 16) but when my peers run the code on Windows they get the following error...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "xlsToCsv.py", line 35, in <module>
    explode(k)
  File "xlsToCsv.py", line 25, in explode
    f.write(ret)
  File "C:\Users\AUser\Anaconda3\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\ufb01' in position 64253: character maps to <undefined>
```

I have tried adding the the line `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` to the head of the file with no effect.

I would love any suggestion that gave me good cross platform performance and any insights to the problem are appreciated!

Comment: The coding spec is for the Python source file and has nothing to do with the error you're getting while writing to the CSV file. If you want to write UTF-8 encoded text to a file in Python 3, you have to explicitly request `encoding='utf-8'` when opening the file. Otherwise you'll get the default locale encoding. For Windows you can see that's your system locale's ANSI codepage, 1252.

Comment: @eryksun you should write as answer...

Comment: That is it indeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Line 13 needs to read

```
        with open(inputFile+".folder"+"/sheet"+str(k)+".csv", 'w', encoding="utf-8") as f:
```